# UICollectionView on iOS15 problems on tap

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios15

I'm facing with some strange behaviors with `UICollectionView` in `iOS15`.

I have a simple memory game with 4x6 cards grid. Every card has two `UIImageView`, one is for the back and another is for the face.

[image]

1. When I tap on a card, I have to show the face of the card. So in the `didSelectItemAt` I hide the back and unhide the face. Result: nothings happen!
   I have to move the code from `didSelectItemAt` to `cellForItemAt` and call `.reloadData()`
2. As second step I have to apply a card flip effect to the card after the tap. Even in this case, nothins happen if I work inside `didSelectItemAt` method; but in this case if I move the code to `cellForItemAt` the animation is performed... but not only on the cell I tapped: it's applied on other 2 or 3 cells that I never touched before. This seems to be a reuse problem, but I'm sure my code is good and work on older versione of iOS.

Ideas? Maybe somethings is changed in `iOS15`?

Comment: Can you add some code maybe from `didSelectItemAt` and `cellForItemAt`?